# Checkbox in QToolbar

Tags: checkbox, qt5, toolbar

How can I add a checkbox to a `QToolbar`? You can add a `QAction` and `setCheckable(true)` on it, but that gives a toggle button rather than an actual checkbox.

Comment: Are you looking for [`QToolBar::insertWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#insertWidget)?

Comment: No because I want it to be a `QAction`, e.g. so it can be inserted into a menu too. `QAction` works perfectly, it's just that the style is wrong.

Comment: The only other suggestion I can think of is to use a [`QWidgetAction`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html) rather than a plain `QAction`.